# POST with curl not working. But can be done with form

Tags: php, curl

I want to POST request to this site:
https://api.telegram.org/myToken/sendphoto

I created a form for do that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://api.telegram.org/MYTOKEN/sendphoto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">
    <input type="hidden" value="108432389" name="chat_id">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works very good. the following headers sent:

```
-----------------------------25522111424583
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="Untitled.png"
Content-Type: image/png

 PNG
```

I write the following script for do this with cURL:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/TOKEN/SendPhoto');
$cfile = new CURLFile('ur.png','image/png','photo');
$data = array('chat_id' => '108432389', 'photo' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res=curl_exec($ch);
echo $res;
?>
```

But it's not working, where is my wrong?

Comment: What does $res contain ? Do you get error 500 or something ?

Comment: @Answers_Seeker I got Bad Gateway error..

Comment: [Error502](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm)

Comment: hopefully `MYTOKEN` and `TOKEN` are just placeholders for the real token, but otherwise you're using two different urls... But also `Sendphoto` and `sendPhoto`... many servers are going to be cAse SEnsItiVe...

Comment: @MarcB They are real dude.

Comment: And the lowercase in your form target whereas your curl request contains uppercase characters ?

Comment: @Answers_Seeker No. It's not important for Server. It looks to them as the same

Comment: And curl_error($ch) returns exactly what....? (http://php.net/curl_error)

Comment: @D.K. It says : couldn't open file "ur.png" 
But the ur.png is located in script directory..

Comment: ls -la on the script directory ? Are you using apache ?

Comment: Test if your curl works correctly e.g. by using this script:
http://www.nextscripts.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-curlssl-is-working-properly/

Comment: Check the permissions on your image file if it's positioned well.

Comment: And you realize you are connecting via HTTP in your html form and then via HTTPS in your PHP code, right?

Answer (score 0):

**It solved.**
This line:

```
$cfile = new CURLFile('ur.png','image/png','photo');
```

Should change to :

```
$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath('ur.png'),'image/png','photo.png');
```